# Why does FileZilla descend into a directory when deleting?

Tags: ftp, filezilla

Why does FileZilla itterrate through each file in a folder and delete each one instead of just deleting the folder? I know this sounds like a simple question, and it probably has the simple answer that FTP doesn't delete folders, but I was just wondering if anyone could shed some light on this issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You've answered your own question - there's no concept in ftp of 'removing a directory and everything below it' with one command.  Most FTP clients therefore iterate through every file one at a time, and then remove the parent directory.

Comment: So what happens if you try to remove a directory with stuff in it? An error?

Comment: Yes, depending on the FTP client you use, you'll get an error, or it'll iterate through everything and remove the files.  Command line client error example -> ftp> rmdir todo / 550 todo: Do not specify an existing file.